# Why does sscanf read more than expected?

Tags: c, scanf

`sscanf` supports `%n` to count how many bytes are read.

Why does sscanf sometimes read additional bytes?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *data = "X\n \n\x09\n \x10\n";
    int len = 0;

    sscanf(data, "X%n", &len);
    printf("%i\n", len);

    sscanf(data, "X\n%n", &len);
    printf("%i\n", len);

    return 0;
}
```

This program prints:

```
1
7
```

I would expect:

```
1
2
```

(1 for `X` and 2 for `X\n`.)

Why does it read more bytes than expected?

Comment: All white-space is equal for the `scanf` family of functions. Putting a space in a `scanf` format string will cause it to skip all consecutive spaces.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude .  All white-space is equal for the scanf family of functions" --> except within `"%[....]"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf):

> The **format** string consists of
>
> - non-whitespace multibyte characters except %: each such character in the format string consumes exactly one identical character from the
>   input stream, or causes the function to fail if the next character on
>   the stream does not compare equal.
> - whitespace characters: any single whitespace character in the format string consumes all available consecutive whitespace characters from
>   the input (determined as if by calling isspace in a loop). Note that
>   there is no difference between "\n", " ", "\t\t", or other whitespace
>   in the format string.

Thus, your `\n` in the second format string will cause the function to consume all remaining whitespace characters – which is actually all 6 characters following the `X` and preceding the `0x10`.